# Polling a email using async await c#

Tags: c#

I'm creating a console app that would:

1. Call a method to check an email account(I've done this step)
2. Convert the attachemnt to pdf(I've done this step)
3. Then once the conversion is complete wait 30 seconds
4. Repeat the previous 3 steps continously

I've done steps 1) and 2) in the `ProcessMailMessages()` method. 
The following code works but I want to know if I am on the right track or is there a better way to poll a email client?

```
    private static int secondsToWait = 30 * 1000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool run = true;
        do
        {
            try
            {
                Task theTask = ProcessEmailTaskAsync();
                theTask.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("<p>Error in Client</p> <p>Exception</p> <p>" + e.Message + "</p><p>" + e.StackTrace + "</p> ");
            }
            GC.Collect();

        } while (run);

    }

    static async Task ProcessEmailTaskAsync()
    {
        var result = await EmailTaskAsync();
    }

    static async Task<int> EmailTaskAsync()
    {
        await ProcessMailMessages();
        await Task.Delay(secondsToWait);
        return 1;
    }

    static async Task ProcessMailMessages()
    {
        ...............................................................................
    }
```

Comment: If you use IMAP, you can have the server tell you as soon as a message arrives.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping in main, you could use a timer.  In main, you would set up the timer and then you could just wait on a Console.Readline() to keep the console from closing.

**Edit -- here's an example**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int MilliSecondsToWait = 30000;
        private static System.Timers.Timer EmailTimer;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EmailTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(MilliSecondsToWait);
            EmailTimer.Elapsed += EmailTimer_Elapsed;
            EmailTimer.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            // if you hit enter, the app will exit.  It is possible for the user to exit the app while a mail download is occurring.  
            // I'll leave it to you to add some flags to control that situation (just trying to keep the example simple)
        }

        private static void EmailTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            // stop the timer to prevent overlapping email downloads if the current download takes longer than MilliSecondsToWait
            EmailTimer.Stop();
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Email Download in progress.");
                // get your email.
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                // handle any errors -- if you let an exception rise beyond this point, the app will be terminated.
            }
            finally
            {
                // start the next poll
                EmailTimer.Start();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works well, its avoiding the use of timers! and also making your code asynchronous with the async/await (TPL). You are on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

This is a gratuitous use of async/await since it is a console app and you are just blocking until the call completes anyway.  Might as well just call ProcessMailMessages() from inside your do/while loop and be done with it.